# A byte Property that should be 0 if the value would be negative?

Tags: c#, properties, byte

I got a problem with a byte property.
I want the attribute to be 0 if an amount is subtracted that would set the number below 0.

My problem is that in a property I only get the value field where the calculation is already finished and the value is not negative but the amount that would have been negative subtracted from the max value of byte.

Changing the attribute type to sbyte is not option.

Is there any way to ensure that 4 minus 5 is 0 and not 255 without writing an explicit setter method and only using a getter property?

Comment: Is changing the property type to `int` an option? This is what .NET does in general.

Comment: You might want to look into the `checked` keyword.

Comment: @minitech, `int` doesn't solve the 0 problem. @32bitkid, `checked` creates an exception problem.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Actually, `int` does solve the problem. [This is what I mean.](http://codepad.org/0bsE2lcb)

Comment: An exception *problem*? Its an overflow. That sounds pretty exceptional in this case.

Comment: @minitech, I see your point, the int allows you to validate and adjust the negative.

Comment: @32bitkid, his question indicates it's *not* exceptional per his rules. Perhaps it should be. But maybe he's writing a score system like SO, for example, where your rep can never go to 0. Downvotes with their -2 penalty have no effect on a user at 1.

Comment: Thinking about this more, you have a business rule for math that you are apparently trying to enforce via a setter, which is not where the math is happening. *Enforce the rule where the math is.* Using an integer as a backing property still creates problems, as the range for integer is far greater than what you need. You might only store 0-255, but someone could try to *give* you 2 billion. Checked arithmetic is also not something you can enforce at the setter, it has to be enforced where the calculations are happening.

Answer (score 2):

First, avoid `byte` for general integral use. Operating on `int` is faster, gives you more flexibility and byte will only save space if you pack them in, and even then the saving won't be significant until you've millions of such objects.

Now, you aren't clear where the "number that is subtracted is".

If the can't-be-negative rule is a matter of the state (rather than "it's negative really but displays as zero, and e.g. -3 plus 2 will still show zero because internally it's zero"), then enforce that rule at the point where the sutraction happens.

```
private void Subtract(int subtrahend)
{
  value = Math.Max(value - subtrahend, 0);
}
```

If it should beinternally negative but display as zero then, just do that in the getter

```
public byte ByteForSomeReason
{
  get { return Math.Max(value, 0); }
}
```

Or indeed, do so in a setter. What do you have against setters setting values, I would rather suspect that they'd be good at that.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, where the backing property is an int:

```
    private int m_TestValue;
    public byte TestValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_TestValue < 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return (byte)m_TestValue;
            }
        }
        set {
            m_TestValue = value;
        }
    }
```

**Update**

Thanks to 32bitkid, I now realize the above solution will not work because any negative value will be converted to a positive value prior to reaching the setter.

The only way to solve this, other than checking the value prior to assignment, is to change the data type of the property to an int, but then provide a byte property that provides the desired functionality.

For example:

```
    public int TestValue {get; set; }

    public byte TestValueAsByte
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.TestValue < 0)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return (byte)this.TestValue;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            this.TestValue = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution doesn't make any sense. `foo.TestValue = 0; foo.TestValue -= 128; Assert.AreEqual(foo.TestValue, 0);` The assertion fails, because its actually equal to `128`. Because the overflow happens outside of the scope of your private m_TestValue, and it just gets assigned the overflown value of +128.

Comment: @32bitkid: Thanks for pointing that out. I rarely work with bytes so did not realize the extent of the implicit overflow conversion. I have modified the answer with a suggested solution.